# get value of the select box in a form

Tags: php, html, mysql

im tryin to get the selected value from select box i used this to get the result

```
$receiver=$_POST['receiver'];
```

but i keep getting the result 0 anyone ?

```
<form method="post" action="new.php?send"> 
<label for="select">

<select name="receiver" value="Select" size="1">

<?php
$sql = "SELECT fullname FROM users"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    { 
            $id=$row["id"]; 
            $name=$row["fullname"]; 
            $options .= '<option name="selected" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }

echo $options; ?>
</option>

</select>
<input id="send" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL is wrong. You are trying to print the ID, but you are not selecting it. Also, there is an unneeded `</option>` right before the closing tag of your select - that might cause problems too.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT id, fullname FROM users";` As for the rest of the code, use @user2443767 solution, it's much cleaner. But you should initialize $options before you start appending your HTML to it.

Answer (score 0):

select id,fullname from users

so that you can fetch id and in last you are writing .no need o